# Need a select for update like functionality with guava cache

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, guava, semaphore

I have two classes and a third singleton class containing guava cache object. I use this cache in class A to perform get(key) and increment when its called and it is called at a rate of 3000/minute. There is class B that uses get(key) adds this value to db and  put a 0 against the key. It can lead to problems if both A and B read same value at a time.
For eg if value for key was 12,both reads 12 ,B sets to 0 then A again sets it to 13.
Kindly suggest what to do.

Comment: Class B is called at an interval of every 15 minutes to add to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cache.asMap().compute(key, (k, v) -> v==null ? 1 : v+1)
```

for A and

```
int[] result = {0};
cache.asMap().computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> {
    result[0] = v;
    return 0; // or null if you want to remove the entry
});
```

for B. The map view is `ConcurrentMap`, which locks computing on the key.

You probably don't need a cache at all. Consider using `ConcurrentHashMap`, `AtomicLongMap`, or (as Xaerxess noted) [ConcurrentHashMultiset](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html) (with the last choice being probably the best as multisets are meant for counting).

Comment: I agree that OP probably doesn't need cache, I would also recommend [`ConcurrentHashMultiset`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html) over `AtomicLongMap`, because it deals with zero values out of the box, if this is what class B does (i.e. removes it from "cache").